# How can i group coordinates by their timestamp values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of coordinates and the end goal is to group coordinates that are within 30 minutes from each other.

Any pointers on how i might achieve this in Javascript?, The sample data that i'm using is as below.

```
{
  "gps_locations": [{
    "type": "gps_location",
    "properties": {
      "layer": "Features",
      "device": "0",
      "timestamp": "21.08.2018 at 22:45:04",
      "unixtime": 1534891504
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-90.3837, -0.66886666666667]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "gps_location",
    "properties": {
      "layer": "Features",
      "device": "0",
      "timestamp": "21.08.2018 at 16:05:04",
      "unixtime": 1534867504
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-78.494933333333, -0.21085]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "gps_location",
    "properties": {
      "layer": "Features",
      "device": "0",
      "timestamp": "18.01.2018 at 01:32:03",
      "unixtime": 1516239123
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-78.494993333333, -0.20414]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "gps_location",
    "properties": {
      "layer": "Features",
      "device": "0",
      "timestamp": "31.07.2010 at 09:02:48",
      "unixtime": 1280566968
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [13.03573045, 47.466879033333]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "gps_location",
    "properties": {
      "layer": "Features",
      "device": "0",
      "timestamp": "31.07.2010 at 07:02:04",
      "unixtime": 1280559724
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [13.03573045, 47.466879033333]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "gps_location",
    "properties": {
      "layer": "Features",
      "device": "0",
      "timestamp": "31.07.2010 at 07:02:04",
      "unixtime": 1280559724
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [13.03573045, 47.466879033333]
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: What does that mean, though, "within 30 minutes from each other"?  What happens if you have 12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45, 1:00, 1: 15, 1: 30, 1:45, and 2:00?  They could all be one group because they are each within 30 minutes of at least one other, but they cover a two-hour span.  So how would you want these grouped?

Comment: As long as the time-gap between any of the two locations in less that 30 minutes they will all fall into the same group until from your example, if the next timestamp is say `2:31` then we start another group and compare the timestamps like we did for the first group etc ..hope that makes it clearer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one version that might work for you:

```js
const last = (xs) => xs[xs.length - 1]

const groupByDiff = (diff, period) => (locs) => locs.sort(diff).reduce(
  (all, loc) => {
    if (!all.length || diff(loc, last(last(all))) > period) {
      all.push([])
    }
    last(all).push(loc)
    return all;
  },
  []
)

const toDate = (ts) => new Date(`${ts.slice(6, 10)}-${ts.slice(3, 5)}-${ts.slice(0, 2)}T${ts.slice(14)}`)
const timestampDifference = (a, b) => toDate(a.properties.timestamp) - toDate(b.properties.timestamp)

const input = {"gps_locations": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [13.03573045, 47.466879033333], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"device": "0", "layer": "Features", "timestamp": "31.07.2010 at 07:02:04", "unixtime": 1280559724}, "type": "gps_location"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [13.03573045, 47.466879033333], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"device": "0", "layer": "Features", "timestamp": "31.07.2010 at 07:02:04", "unixtime": 1280559724}, "type": "gps_location"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [13.03573045, 47.466879033333], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"device": "0", "layer": "Features", "timestamp": "31.07.2010 at 09:02:48", "unixtime": 1280566968}, "type": "gps_location"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [-78.494993333333, -0.20414], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"device": "0", "layer": "Features", "timestamp": "18.01.2018 at 01:32:03", "unixtime": 1516239123}, "type": "gps_location"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [-78.494933333333, -0.21085], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"device": "0", "layer": "Features", "timestamp": "21.08.2018 at 16:05:04", "unixtime": 1534867504}, "type": "gps_location"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [-90.3837, -0.66886666666667], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"device": "0", "layer": "Features", "timestamp": "21.08.2018 at 22:45:04", "unixtime": 1534891504}, "type": "gps_location"}]}

const groupedLocations = groupByDiff(timestampDifference, 1000 * 60 * 30)(input.gps_locations)
console.log(groupedLocations)
```

Note the API: the function `groupByDiff` is fairly generic, accepting a function that finds the numeric difference between two element and a threshold period in milliseconds, and returning a function that accepts a list of objects and sorts and groups them based upon that period.

`last` is a simple helper function to avoid repeating `xs[xs.length]` several times, including a nested one.  `toDate` takes one of your timestamps and turns it into a date.  `timestampDifference` takes two locations, retrieves their timestamps, converts both to Dates, and takes their difference (which is expressed in milliseconds.)

Finally, `groupByDiff` is the main function.  We supply it first with `timestampDifference` and 30 minutes, and then supply the resulting function with the `gps_locations` property of your original data and get back a list of lists of locations.

And of course `const groupedLocations = groupByDiff(timestampDifference, 1000 * 60 * 30)` is a function that you can reuse any time you have this data structure.  `groupByDiff` you can reuse across many data structures.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, i guess i had taken the long route. I also has used the unixtime values for comparison that way i wouldn't have to convert the strings to date. That works better though thanks a lot